# MongoDB - Store millisecond instead of Date

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using PHP as server side language. I'm getting date in millisecond from my ajax request and converted it into MongoDate, then i store it into MongoDB. Like below.

```
$date = new MongoDate($millisecond / 1000);
$db->test->insert({"date": $date});
```

Again, when i need date in my javascript, i'm getting MongoDate and and converted into millisecond and i pass it to my UI. Like below

```
foreach($cursor as $row) {
    $row["date"] = $row["date"]->sec * 1000;
}
```

Instead, why should i not store date as millisecond instead of Dateobject? Still i can compare two dates, even-though i store it as millisecond.

Any other disadvantages would i face in future, while i do reports with date as millisecond?

Comment: Aggregation framework currently only funcitons on date fields

Comment: Maybe this helps: You can extract Date/Time (including MS) from the MongoId Object.

Comment: @Sammaye Hi, i store millisecond as number. Won't mongodb allow number in aggregation?

Comment: Not currently, it must be a date field if you wish to use the date operators, if you have no need of the date operators then there is no problem

Comment: @Sammaye Ok. It's valid point. Do you feel any other disadvantages?

Comment: Nope, a milisecond tiemstamp is easy enough to use with PHPs date functions, and it is easy to use in MR with JavaScripts own date functions too

Comment: Cool. For the same reasons, i'm storing date as millisecond. Thanks for confirming. Could you please elaborate your opinion on Answer section? May be, would help to someone who visit it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only place I can think of where it would matter if a date field were actually stored as the `ISODate` type is within the aggregation framework, however, I have no doubt that such a constraint will eventually change when casting becomes possible (this I would like to see).

Other than that your value is easily usable within both PHP/any other language and Map Reduces own date constructs. With this in mind I see no problem if you don't require the aggregation frameworks date operators.

Comment: What do you mean by MR?

Comment: @user10 Map Reduce sorry, used to it called that